# Git push new branch as specific user picks up old commit

Tags: git, gitlab

In order to trigger some automation, I need to push to a gitlab repo as a specific user with a branch name following some specific formatting. For the sake of reference, let's call that user `Joe Programmer <jp@company.com>` and the branch name `example-branch`.

There's a pre-existing commit that I want to grab and push to gitlab, so I change my user

```
git config --local user.name "Joe Programmer"
git config --local user.email "jp@company.com"
```

delete the branch, if it exists, and push that delete to the repo as well

```
git push origin --delete refs/heads/example-branch
git branch -D example-branch
```

checkout from my known-good commit

```
git checkout good_commit
```

and branch from it

```
git checkout -b example-branch good_commit
```

then I commit with an empty change set and push to origin.

```
git commit -m "triggering automation" --allow-empty
git push origin example-branch
```

However when I look on Gitlab, I see that it's picked up not only my empty commit (as Joe Programmer) but also the previous commit I've called `good_commit` above, attributed to the actual person whose made that commit.

How do I most-easily omit `good_commit`, so the only thing that pushes to remote is my commit as Joe Programmer?

Comment: to clarify: since `good_commit` is the first commit in this new branch (and it is not committed by Joe Programmer), the automation does not trigger correctly.

Comment: Try git checkout --orphan example_branch good_commit? https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---orphanltnewbranchgt

Comment: @York that sounds doable, but I noticed that `git log --all` still shows the previous commits on the local repo. That might go away on remote, but I don't have a way of testing that! Can you confirm? If so: feel free to write up an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, but probably not perfect, is to amend the last commit.

So instead of an empty commit, you will do:

```
git commit  --amend --no-edit --author "Joe Programmer <jp@company.com>"
git push origin example-branch
```

As far as I understood, you need a change of the author, so also added the `--author`

So the downside is the duplicate commits with the same content (but different hash) per branch, but maybe it's better than those empty "triggering automation" commits.

Comment: Does this amend the commit where it exists on the old branch, too (`good_commit`)? That's not a dealbreaker, since `good_commit` is the tip of a throwaway branch in our workflow, but would be good to know...

Comment: If you have a branch with commit A+B, then after branch and amend, the old branch still have A+B and the new one has A+C.