# Gitlab project's "Activity Log" shows branch pushed by wrong user

Tags: git, gitlab

Closely related to [this question I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596477/git-push-new-branch-as-specific-user-picks-up-old-commit), but with new information from on high about how the automation I'm trying to trigger functions.

I'm trying to push a branch as `Joe Programmer <jp@company.com>` where the branch follows some naming format. For sake of brevity, let's call that `example-branch`. Our normal automation clones the repo, does some work, and pushes back as `Robot User <robot@company.com>`. That's working perfectly, but the downstream automation uses *information in the Activity log* of the project to determine who is responsible for the new `example-branch`, and if I want that to be `Joe Programmer` (and I do), I need to make the *Activity Log* read:

```
Joe Programmer pushed new branch example-branch
```

As a final step in our process, I change user with:

```
git config --local user.name "Joe Programmer"
git config --local user.email "jp@company.com"
```

then delete the branch (if it exists) with:

```
git push origin --delete refs/heads/example-branch
git branch -D example-branch
```

checkout from my known-good commit (this is after the work that `Robot User` does to the repo) with:

```
git checkout good_commit
```

branch from it, using the `--orphan` flag that [@congbaoguier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4573573/congbaoguier) pointed me at

```
git checkout --orphan example-branch good_commit
```

then make an empty commit to kick off the automation and push to origin

```
git commit -m "triggering automation" --allow-empty
git push origin example-branch
```

However what I see in Gitlab's activity log is:

```
# ed: newest events come first in this log

Robot User pushed new branch example-branch
Robot User deleted branch example-branch
```

Since I've changed my user before deleting the branch from remote, deleting the branch from local, checking out, branching, *and* making the commit, I'm not sure why Gitlab still thinks that `Robot User` is responsible for the branch push.

Comment: I'm thinking it's detecting it by ssh key. The system has `Robot User`'s SSH private key and not `Joe Programmer`'s, but I don't have a great way to test that.